# How to append dataframe with selected columns having higher feature score

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feature-selection

Hi I am new to python let me know if the question is not clear.
Here is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df_test)
```

> ```
>     age     bmi     children      charges
> 0   19    27.900         0     16884.92400
> 1   18    33.770         1     1725.55230
> 2   28    33.000         3     4449.46200
> 3   33    22.705         0     21984.47061
> ```

I am applying select 'k' best feature selection using **chi squared test** for this numerical data

```
X_clf = numeric_data.iloc[:,0:(col_len-1)] 
y_clf = numeric_data.iloc[:,-1]
bestfeatures = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=2)
fit = bestfeatures.fit(X_clf,y_clf)
dfscores = pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
dfcolumns = pd.DataFrame(X_clf.columns)
featureScores = pd.concat([dfcolumns,dfscores],axis=1)
```

This is my output:

> ```
>     Feature        Score
> 0       age     6703.764216
> 1       bmi     1592.481991
> 2  children     1752.136519
> ```

I wish to now append my dataframe to contain only the features with 2 highest scores. However I wish to do so without **hardcoding** the column names while appending into my dataframe.

I have tried to store the column names into a list and append those with highest score but am getting a Value error. Is there any method/function i could try by storing the selected columns and then appending them based on they're scores?

Expected Output: Column 'bmi' is not there as it has lowest of 3 scores

> ```
>       age     children      charges
>  0      19         0     16884.92400
>  1      18         1     1725.55230
>  2      28         3     4449.46200
>  3      33         0     21984.47061
> ```

Comment: Which columns do you want to append the Feature and Score data to?

Comment: @BenPap I wish to append the feature columns with highest score (in this case age and children and remove bmi) to my dataframe so that only the imprtant features are selected as part of my dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to work on the dataframe `featureScores` to keep the first 2 features with the highest `Score` and then use this values as a list to filter the columns in the original dataframe. Something along the lines of:

```
important_features = featureScores.sort_values('Score',ascending=False)['Feature'].values.tolist()[:2] + ['charges']
filtered_df = df[important_features]
```

The `sort_values()` is to make sure the features (in case there are more) are sorted from highest score to lowest score. We then are creating a list of the first 2 values of the column `Feature` (which has been sorted already) with `.values.tolist()[:2]`. Since you seem to also want to include the column `charges` in your output, we are appending it manually with `+['charges']` to our list of important_features.

Finally, we're creating a `filtered_df` by selecing only the `important_features` columns from the original `df`.

#### Edit based on comments:

If you can guarantee `charges` will be the last column in your original `df` then you can simply do:

```
important_features = featureScores.sort_values('Score',ascending=False)['Feature'].values.tolist()[:2] + [df.columns[-1]]
filtered_df = df[important_features]
```

I see you have previously defined your `y` column with `y_clf = numeric_data.iloc[:,-1]` you can then use `y_clf.columns` or `[df.columns[-1]]`, either should work fine.

Comment: yes thank you this seems to do the trick. Is it possible if I can do the same thing without hardcoding the target column (in this case 'charges')?

Comment: Well, the thing is, you would want to have previously defined your X and Y columns and then you would pass the `y` column as an argument without having to hardcode `charges`. There has to be at least one point in time in which you will need to tell python that the target column is `charges` otherwise it'll be impossible for it to know. **UNLESS** you can guarantee `charges` will always be the last column in the original dataframe, in which case you can check my edit.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helps you solve your issue, or let me know if you have further issues

Answer (score 0):

So first you want to find out which features have the largest values, then find the Featurename of the columns you do not want to see.

```
colToDrop = feature.iloc[~feature['Score'].nlargest(2)]['Feature'].values
```

Next we just filter the original df and remove those columns from the columns list

```
df[df.columns.drop(colToDrop)]
```